# Most efficient PHP str_replace on array if row only has 5% chance of containing target?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have a 15,000 row PHP array. I need to iterate through each row to generate a 15,000 row Javascript array. Each row of the PHP array has a 5% chance of containing one or more HTML special characters like `&amp;#243;` that I need to replace with the equivalent javascript hex. There are about 50 HTML special characters I have to look out for and replace, so I'd use `str_replace(array_of_HTML_targets, array_of_hex_replacements, haystack)`. Is it more efficient to:

1. Go through each line of the PHP array, search for an ampersand, and if one exists do the search and replace (considering this will apply for only 5% of the rows)
2. Execute the search and replace on the entire array
3. Concatenate the array into one giant string and execute the search and replace on the giant string
4. Other idea? Please specify

Btw, reason for 15,000 PHP array is this is a data visualization app.

Comment: "I have a 15,000 row PHP array." I don't know what you're doing, but there is without doubt a better way.

Comment: Sounds like you need to know about the [`html_entity_decode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: `str_replace()` (or any other selective replacement function) will, by its nature, search through the string to find the relevant characters, so doing a search for them manually first isn't going to speed things up at all. So I'd say your option 1 is pointless over-complication.

Comment: Spudley, thanks for your input. The reason I didnt do html_entity_decode is I wasn't sure how to get javascript hex codes out of it and wasn't sure if str_replace would be more efficient for the 50 special chars I'm looking for. The reason I thought about searching the string for an ampersand first before doing the search and replace is it seems that would look first for 1 character before looking for 50 strings, since the replacing would only be necessary in 1 out of 20 rows. Just my thoughts, I could definitely be wrong...

Answer (score 4):

Since you already need to dump your PHP data into a string (probably JSON), you might as well work on the final string, like so:

```
$json = json_encode($your_php_array);
$unhtmlref = preg_replace_callback("/&#(x[0-9a-f]+|\d+);/",function($m) {
    if( $m[1][0] == "x") $m[1] = substr($m[1],1);
    else $m[1] = dechex($m[1]);
    return sprintf("\\u%04s",$m[1]);
},$json);
```

This is safe, because HTML character codes don't have any special meaning in a JSON string.

That said, I have a function in my JavaScript "utility belt" that does something similar:

```
function unHTMLref(str) {
    // take a string and return it, with all HTML character codes parsed
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
    return div.firstChild.nodeValue;
}
```

So basically you can either parse before, or after. Personally, I'd prefer "after" because it shifts some of the "grunt" work to the browser, allowing the server to do more important things.

Comment: Good answer, taught me something as well!

Comment: This is a good idea shifting the grunt work to the browser. I'm going to re-write to do this. Apologies for not marking this as an answer since it's more a workaround, even though I think I'm going to go with this workaround